# How to collect the normal vectors and the vector of another object at one point to evaluate Dot product?

Tags: shaders, normals

It is necessary to collect the normal vectors and the position vector of the third-party object at one point and perform the operation Dot product.

How can I do that?

[image]

Comment: What do you mean with "collect at one point"? This makes no sense for direction vectors like normals. What is the white vector? Please be more precise.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if I understand your question correctly, but maybe this is what you want: You want the dot product of the face normals of an object and the position of a different object like an empty for example, and this inside the *Shader Editor*?

In this example I have a material on Suzanne where I calculate the dot product of the face normals to the position of an empty:

[image: dot product]

Depending on what you want to achieve it might be necessary to *Normalize* the vectors:

[image: normalize]